# What are the steps to securing encryption keys/databases on an unsecured DAAS provider?

Tags: virtualization, cloud-computing

Most Desktop As A Service providers store their virtual hard drives and the [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machines)s RAM in a way that allows them to access their contents.

Choosing a provider who offers a 'no-knowledge of server' option looks like the easiest solution.  However, companies rarely choose those, and there are significant financial considerations when changing a cloud provider after you've initially chosen one.

What would be the theoretical steps to securing encryption keys and their associated databases?(encrypting things like basics OS programs is not required).

What would be the steps to encrypt the whole filesystem and RAM (since data can stolen if accessed while in RAM) if encrypting only the sensitive data turns out to be more expensive?

Comment: Note: the wanted case here is for small servers, not for end-user Desktop access.

Comment: @Xander: Really thank YOU for editing my post. But why are you deleting the desktop-as-service tag again? You didn't give any explanation about it in the edit history. I just want to avoid edit wars.

Comment: Because I'm the one who originally added it, and as a moderator felt it wasn't appropriate and deleted it, I'm promoting consistency by accepting that position.

Comment: @Xander: Ok I understand. The fact was that a user replaced it with visualization and I roll-backed his edit.